# Can I lock a particular Google Apps worksheet using a script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to lock a particular Google Apps worksheet using a script?

I have this code that renames the current spreadsheet to whatever you enter in the input box.

```
// The code below will rename the active sheet to what you enter in the input box
var myValue = Browser.inputBox("Enter: LastMonth - Year");
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet(myValue);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("A1").setValue(myValue);
```

What can I add to the code above that will lock that same worksheet i just renamed only allowing me to edit that worksheet.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
// Enables sheet protection for  this sheet
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var permissions = sheet.getSheetProtection();
permissions.setProtected(true);
sheet.setSheetProtection(permissions);
```

See Spreadsheet Services - [Class PageProtection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_pageprotection#setProtected)

Comment: Can i lock that same worksheet i just renamed and specify the username that has access to edit the worksheet or does it only using the current logged-in user?

Answer (score 3):

Since [Class PageProtection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_pageprotection) is currently deprecated you may use the [Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) to achieve the same:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.protect();
```

To unprotect when needed you may use the following code snippet:

```
var protection = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
 if (protection && protection.canEdit()) {
   protection.remove();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Code below found in [Spreadsheet Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/page-protection#setProtected), as @ScampMichael said.

Adds a user to the list of users who can edit the sheet, if it is protected.

```
// Add the "user@example.com" user to the list of users who can edit this sheet
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var permissions = sheet.getSheetProtection();
 permissions.addUser('user@example.com');
 permissions.setProtected(true);
 sheet.setSheetProtection(permissions);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of protections offered by the modern [Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) class (as is the case in the UI):

- A protection which displays a warning when anybody attempt to edit a cell.
- A protection which denies write access to certain users altogether.

Although the second option sounds ideal, there is an [important caveat](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#removeEditor(String)):

> Neither the owner of the spreadsheet nor the current user can be removed.

For my usecase of wanting to discourage *anybody* from editing the sheet while the script is running, I found the best solution to be to add a protection warning, and hide the sheet:

```js
function lockSheet_(sheet) {
  sheet.hideSheet();
  const protection = sheet.protect();
  protection.setDescription('MyApplication Lock');
  protection.setWarningOnly(true);
  return protection;
}

function unlockSheet_(sheet, lock) {
  lock.remove();
  sheet.showSheet();
}
```

Usage:

```js
  const lock = lockSheet_(sheet);

  // ...

  unlockSheet_(sheet, lock);
```